# Refactor main.go to another packages

Tags: go, methods, struct, module

Good, first of all, I am learning Go and I am a deaf person and English is not my main language.

I'm having a hard time understanding the videos, even though they are subtitled, I don't understand very well many times. Even so, I really want to learn.

I want to understand why methods in the same package (main) works, ex.:

main.go

```
type application struct {
    config config
    logger *log.Logger
}
```

routes.go

```
func (app *application) routes() *httprouter.Router {
    router := httprouter.New()

    router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/status", app.statusHandler)
    
    return router
}
```

then I refactor like this:

main.go

```
app := &config.Application{
    Config: cfg,
    Logger: logger,
}
```

config.go

```
type Application struct {
    Config Config
    Logger *log.Logger
}
```

routes.go

```
func (app *config.Application) Routes() *httprouter.Router {
    router := httprouter.New()

    router.HandlerFunc(http.MethodGet, "/status", app.statusHandler)

    return router
}
```

statusHandler.go

```
func (app *config.Application) StatusHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    currentStatus := config.AppStatus{
        Status:      "OK",
        Environment: app.Config.Env,
        Version:     app.Config.Version,
    }

    js, err := json.MarshalIndent(currentStatus, "", "\t")
    if err != nil {
        app.Logger.Println(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write(js)

}
```

But app are underlined and say me: invalid receiver type *config.Application.

I would be glad if someone can explain me the problem and how to fix this and make it multi-module with methods or other accepted way.

Regards, Pedro.

I have tried to do it with another new project, doing it step by step in case I missed something.
However, I realized that I don't seem to be very clear on the concept of methods.

Comment: The methods for a type can only be defined in the same package as the type. You cannot  define a new method for a type in a different package.

Comment: Thanks for you response. So, how do you approach refactoring to other packages?, Passing it by parameters? I listen to any hints or suggestions.

Comment: You can pass it as param, or you can move source around. In this case, I'd pass the `app` as param, but this is subjective, others may prefer other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you following the [golang tour](https://go.dev/tour/welcome/1).

As explained [here](https://go.dev/tour/basics/1)  go code is made by packages, usually each folder represents its own package.

As answerd by Burak  you can't create [Methods](https://go.dev/tour/methods/1) outside the package that declare the type that they implement.

That said  if you do something like this:

```
 - baseFolder
 |- main 
 |-- main.go (package main)
 |- config
 |-- config.go (package config)
 |-- routes.go (package config)
 |-- statusHandler.go (package config)
```

You can use your code without referencing the "package"

```
func (app *Application) StatusHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
...}
```

And import it on your main.go